# PhotoSwipe - How to make slideshow stop at last slide instead of looping

Tags: css, html, photoswipe

I'm using PhotoSwipe JQuery on a page along with slick slider. I want to navigation arrow to be disabled, once it reaches the final image.

Comment: Did you read the docs?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following information in the documentation of PhotoSwipe:

> **loop - boolean**
>
> Loop slides when using swipe gesture. If set to
> **true** you'll be able to swipe from last to first image. Option is
> always **false** when there are less than 3 slides. This option has no
> relation to arrows navigation. **Arrows loop is turned on permanently**.
> You can **modify this behavior by making custom UI**

.

Answer (score -1):

Just use given below to stop looping after last slid.

var options = {
        loop: false //stop looping
    };

Comment: See Serge's answer above:

loop - boolean

Loop slides when using swipe gesture. If set to true you'll be able to swipe from last to first image. Option is always false when there are less than 3 slides. This option has no relation to arrows navigation. Arrows loop is turned on permanently. You can modify this behavior by making custom UI